# Java/ Writing in the first line, by out.write

Tags: java, file

I try to find a way to write in the first line of a file.

The problem is that I write to the file about 3000 lines (by `out.write`), but just in the end of this writing I have a information that needed to be insert to the first line of this file.

There is a easy way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There is a easy way to do that?

Nope. This isn't a matter of Java being awkward - it's just file systems, which don't generally allow you to *insert* data within a file.

Options:

- Generate the file in memory (3000 lines isn't a lot) and then write it all out when you know the first line
- Write out the file without the first line, then start a *new* file by writing out the first line, and then copying the "old" file line by line
- If you know the *length* of the first line (in bytes) before you start, you could leave enough room, write out the length of the file, and then *overwrite* the first line

Comment: How to "leave enough room" in file ? Could you explain please. Thanks.

Comment: @Oleksandr.Bezhan: Well it only works out if you know exactly how much space you need to leave - but just write spaces (or anything you like) there, then use something like `RandomAccessFile` to overwrite that section of the file at the end. It's hard to be more concrete without more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two stream, one for your current and one for final.
When write end, write information first and then write your current stream to the final stream.

```
OutputStream finalOs;
OutputStream dataOs;
//...write your data
finalOs.write(your information);
finalOs.write(dataOs);// just 4 example
```